# Jsoup get works fine when using breakpoint but doesn't work in normal run

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I have used Jsoup for scraping a website as follows:

```
try {
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url[0]).timeout(10000).maxBodySize(0).execute();
            Document doc = response.parse();
            Elements elements = doc.select("td>img");
            return elements.get(0).select("td>img").get(0).absUrl("src");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return "";
        }
```

The problem is when I set a breakpoint on return line, it works fine but doesn't work in normal run. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I made a mistake and perform a query on result again. The correct code is:

```
return elements.get(0).absUrl("src");
```

by the way, I'm still confused that why it is working in debug mode. When I put a break point, the result of 'select' includes the parent node which is strange.